# How to execute join on already joined columns?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to get a list of posts from a table checking by a specific `taxonomy` id, which can be of three types: region, city and area, also the query that I wrote looks for post which have a `title` similar to a specific searched term, in that case `foo`. This is my query:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wpps_posts.* 
FROM wpps_posts 
LEFT JOIN wpps_term_relationships ON (wpps_posts.ID = wpps_term_relationships.object_id) 
WHERE (
(
    wpps_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN ('161') OR
    wpps_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN ('') OR
    wpps_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN ('')
) 
OR wpps_posts.post_title LIKE '%foo%')
AND wpps_posts.post_type = 'zoacres-property' AND wpps_posts.post_status = 'publish'
GROUP BY wpps_posts.ID ORDER BY wpps_posts.post_title ASC LIMIT 0, 6
```

the main problem here is that I have to search the posts also for the sub taxonomies, for example the `taxonomy` with id 161 is the parent of the taxonomy 143, which is linked to the `wpps_term_taxonomy` table through the column `term_id`, eg:

```
 term_taxonomy_id | term_id | taxonomy        | description | parent | count
      143             161      property-area                    67      1
```

how can I join the sub taxonomies using `term_taxonomy_id` which is an array?

Comment: What exactly is the data type of the column `term_taxonomy_id` - not all DBMS products support proper arrays.

Comment: sorry guys, forgot to add the dbms, is `MySQL`. @a_horse_with_no_name the column `term_taxonomy_id` is `bigint(20)`

Comment: Well, `bigint(20)` is not "an array"... It's a column that can store a single number up to the value of 9223372036854775808

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name a know, but I used the `IN` operator to check if in the `term_taxonomy_id` contains at least one searched references